# How does this for loop check every index number even though it says particularly index 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a solution of code breaker problem and I didn't get the solution.

> SPY GAME: Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order

```
def spy_game(nums):

   code = [0,0,7,'x']

   for num in nums:
       if num == code[0]:
           code.pop(0)   # code.remove(num) also works

   return len(code) == 1
```

How does this for loop check every index number though it says particularly index 0?

Comment: because `.pop(0)` removes the first element from `code` - so the new first element is the next one.

Comment: Ooh thanks Robin that was very helpful my professor would never say that. Thanks again

Comment: Why does your professor need to say it? It is written in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do `code.pop(0)`, you are removing the element at index 0 from the list `code`. When you call your function with `[0, 0, 7]`, the following loop iterations are being made:

```
nums = [0, 0, 7]
code = [0, 0, 7, 'x']

# First iteration
num = 0 (first element of nums)
num == code[0] is true
code[0] is removed
code = [0, 7, 'x']

# Second iteration
num = 0 (second element of nums)
num == code[0] is true
code[0] is removed
code = [7, 'x']

# Third iteration
num = 7 (third element of nums)
num == code[0] is true
code[0] is removed
code = ['x']

# End of the loop
All elements of nums have been iterated, so the loop is over

code = ['x']
len(code) == 1 is true
True is returned
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def spy_game(nums):
    mylist =  list(enumerate(nums))
    myupdatedlist = []

    for a,b in mylist:
        if b ==0 or b ==7:
            myupdatedlist.append(tuple((a,b)))
    if myupdatedlist[0][1] == 7:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    pass
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def spy_game(nums):
    sana = "".join(str(e) for e in nums)

    if "007" in sana:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

List to a string and simply check if 007 in that string.

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this:

```
def myfunc(a):
    for c, b in enumerate(a):
        if b == 0 and a[c+1] == 0 and a[c+2] == 7:
            return True
    return False

myfunc([0, 2, 7])
```

output

```
False
```

Comment: This raises an error for example for `[0, 2, 0]`... (or any wrong input that also ends with a 0)